# How to sort alphabetic index list with foreach loop PHP (Laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new here and new to Laravel.

For my website, I'm building a page with lists that should be ordered alphabetically. I do get the output already, but it's not ordered correctly.

I've got multiple categories containing lists with links, check the image for the visual idea.

Any idea how to insert some kind of sort function within the code I have?

```
@foreach($category['theories'] as $letter => $theories)

                        @if(count($theories) > 0)
                            <div>
                                <h3 class="text-xl mb-1">{{$letter}}</h3>
                                <ul class="mb-4">
                                    @foreach($theories->sortBy('title') as $theory)
                                        <li>
                                            @can(['view-theory'], $theory)
                                                <a href="{{route('theories.show', [$theory->slug])}}" class="no-underline font-bold">
                                                    {{$theory->title}}
                                                </a>
                                            @else
                                                <span class="premium-tag cursor-not-allowed flex flex-row items-center">
                                                    {{$theory->title}} <i class="fas fa-lock ml-1"></i>
                                                </span>
                                            @endcan
                                        </li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        @endif

                  @endforeach
```

I hope somebody is able to help me.

This is what it currently looks like
[image]

Comment: There is no query, which means you might be ignoring the actual issue. Cognitive biases are indeed the topic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: welcom to stackoverflow sander. you could add `->orderBy` clause on your eloquent query to order the data - which is why martin suggested you to provide query. though, i'm not quite sure which part of your screenshot unordered. do you want them to be printed horizontally instead of vertical?

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?